# Recorrer JSON en PHP

Tags: php, json

tengo un problema que no puedo resolver, aun soy novato en esto.
Recibo en un archivo php el siguiente JSON que decodifico de esta forma.

```
$resultado=json_decode($_POST["datos"]);
```

y cuando muestro la variable resultado me arroja lo de abajo.

```
 {"numeros":{"19":1,"8":1,"30":1,"31":1,"35":1,"45":1}}
```

Lo que no logro es poder leerlo para sacar los valores que tiene dentro. Intente de muchas formas y no pude, el error mas común que me tira es este "Trying to get property of non-object".

Intenté recorrerlo con `foreach`, poniéndolo en un arreglo pero no logro hacerlo.

Esta es una de las formas que intente.

```
 foreach ($resultado->numeros as $key => $value) {

 echo $key;

 echo $value;

 }
```

Lo que busco es poder mostrar la clave por ejemplo 19 y su respectivo valor en ese caso 1.

---

Edito mi pregunta para agregar el origen de los datos.

Este es todo el camino de código.

```
     $('#btn_buscar').on('click', function(){

 $.ajax({                        
       type: "POST",                 
       url: 'procesos/estadisticas_jugadas.php',                     
       data: $("#frm_buscar").serialize(), 
       success: function(data)             
       {
                       //alert(data);
                      cargar_estadisticas(data);
                             }  
   });
     return false;
    });



   function cargar_estadisticas(data){
   var estadisticas = JSON.stringify(data);
   $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
 url: 'procesos/tabla_estadisticas.php',
  data: "datos=" + estadisticas,
 success: function (data) {
    alert(data);
  },
  error: function(){
    alert('Error');
  }
 });
 }
```

La Consulta que me arroja los números esta en el siguiente PHP llamado `estadisticas_jugada.php`.

La consulta que guardo en `$sql` no la pongo porque es demasiado larga pero funciona bien de ser necesario edito nuevamente y la agrego.

```
$resultado = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);

 if(!$resultado)
die("Error");
else{


$numeros = array();
 $data = array();

 while($registronumeros=$resultado->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH))
{
$numeros[$registronumeros["Numeros"]]++;

}


$data['numeros'] = $numeros;

echo json_encode($data);

}

mysqli_free_result($resultado);
mysqli_close($mysqli);
?>
```

Este es el archivo donde se generaba el error. o subo corregido y funcionando con esa doble decodificación, estoy intentando ver en que parte  del origen se guarda como string el json así evitar esa doble decodificación.

El archivo se llama `tabla_estadisticas.php`.

```
    <?php
    require_once 'conexion.php';
    $data=json_decode($_POST["datos"]);
    echo 'Resultado vale: ', $data, PHP_EOL;

    $resultado = json_decode($data);

    foreach ($resultado->numeros as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key => $value", PHP_EOL;
     }
     ?>
```

Comment: ¿Podrías hacer un `var_dump($_POST["datos"])` y mostrar en tu pregunta su contenido? He probado tu código y debería funcionar correctamente.

Comment: También nos vendría bien cómo envías esta información a tu PHP, para ver cómo montas los datos y usas `JSON.stringify()` (si lo usas).

Comment: Puf, acabo de ver tu edición y como haces dos saltos (solicitas un documento por ajax que luego envías de nuevo en otra petición ajax) sería mejor que abrieses una nueva pregunta para poder redactar la explicación sin alargar innecesariamente o "intoxicar" esta respuesta.

Comment: esta bien voy a abrir otra pregunta , gracias!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema que estás teniendo es que no recibes directamente un valor JSON, si no que recibes una cadena codificada en JSON:

```
<?php
$_POST['datos'] = '"{\"numeros\":{\"19\":1,\"8\":1,\"30\":1,\"31\":1,\"35\":1,\"45\":1}}"';
$resultado = json_decode($_POST['datos']);
echo 'Resultado vale: ', $resultado, PHP_EOL;
foreach ($resultado->numeros as $key => $value) {
  echo "$key => $value", PHP_EOL;
}
```

El resultado de la ejecución es:

```
Resultado vale: {"numeros":{"19":1,"8":1,"30":1,"31":1,"35":1,"45":1}}
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'numeros' of non-object in /tmp/pr.php on line 5
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /tmp/pr.php on line 5
```

Como puedes ver, `$resultado` vale (como pones en tu pregunta) `{"numeros":{"19":1,"8":1,"30":1,"31":1,"35":1,"45":1}}`, pero como cadena, no como valor JSON, por lo que intentar acceder a la propiedad `numeros` de una cadena te lanza el mensaje de advertencia ***Trying to get property 'numeros' of non-object***.

Así que el problema parece estar en origen (donde montas la cadena a enviar a PHP).

Una solución (sin modificar el origen de los datos) podría ser:

```
<?php
$_POST['datos'] = '"{\"numeros\":{\"19\":1,\"8\":1,\"30\":1,\"31\":1,\"35\":1,\"45\":1}}"';
$resultado = json_decode($_POST['datos']);
echo 'Resultado vale: ', $resultado, PHP_EOL;
/* Ahora decodificamos la cadena decodificada anteriormente */
$resultado = json_decode($resultado);
foreach ($resultado->numeros as $key => $value) {
  echo "$key => $value", PHP_EOL;
}
```

Cuyo resultado es:

```
Resultado vale: {"numeros":{"19":1,"8":1,"30":1,"31":1,"35":1,"45":1}}
19 => 1
8 => 1
30 => 1
31 => 1
35 => 1
45 => 1
```

Aunque decodificar dos veces el JSON obtenido soluciona tu problema, deberías corregirlo en origen (en el código javascript que envía los datos).

Comment: Tu respuesta me ayudo perfectamente! decodificando 2 veces puedo acceder a los datos y eh entendido los errores que me generaba, de igual forma voy a revisar el origen para evitar esta doble decodificación. Voy a subir el codigo de como envio los archivos por post para que puedas revisarlos si deseas la verdad te agradezco muchisimo, a vos y a las demas respuestas, un abrazo gigante.

Comment: Ha sido un placer :) puedes poner el envío en una nueva pregunta por si la gente que está suscrita al tag javascript te responde antes que yo ;)

Answer (score 2):

Puedes poner el segundo argumento de *json_decode* a **true** y así obtener un array asociativo con el que poder trabajar, evitando encontrarte con problemas de objeto.

```
$datos = '{"numeros":{"19":1,"8":1,"30":1,"31":1,"35":1,"45":1}}';

$resultado=json_decode($datos,true);

foreach($resultado['numeros'] as $k => $v)
{
    echo $k; // Esto devuelve las variables por separado

    echo $v;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

El asunto es más sencillo amigos.

Se trata de leer el array en PHP ¿no?

Pues resulta que **¡`$_POST` es precisamente eso, un array!**.

Entonces si tú quieres leer lo que hay en `$_POST["datos"]`, léelo como tal, no tienes por qué convertirlo a JSON.

Prueba esto y verás:

```
$arrDatos=$_POST["datos"];
foreach ($arrDatos as $k=>$v){
    echo "key: $k - value: $v".PHP_EOL;
}
```

Para más pruebas, haz esto:

```
print_r($_POST);
```

Verás que `$_POST` no es otra cosa que **un array**.

---

El único caso en el que tendría sentido lo que intentas, es si tu variable `$_POST` se mostrase así con:

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

---

```
array(1) {
  ["datos"]=>
  string(54) "{"numeros":{"19":1,"8":1,"30":1,"31":1,"35":1,"45":1}}"
}
```

En ese caso sí, habría que acceder a la clave `datos` de tu array `$_POST`, y convertir el valor de esa clave, que no es más que una cadena ( observa que el `var_dump` dice `string(54)`), en JSON, pasándole el parámetro `TRUE` para que te cree un array para PHP, algo así: `$arrDatos=json_decode($_POST["datos"],TRUE);`

En ese caso, `$arrDatos` va a tener esta estructura, lo podrás ver si haces un `var_dump($arrDatos);`:

```
array(1) {
  ["numeros"]=>
  array(6) {
    [19]=>
    int(1)
    [8]=>
    int(1)
    [30]=>
    int(1)
    [31]=>
    int(1)
    [35]=>
    int(1)
    [45]=>
    int(1)
  }
```

Entonces podrás leer la clave `numeros` de ese array en un `foreach`.

El código completo sería entonces este:

```
$arrDatos=json_decode($_POST["datos"],TRUE);

foreach ($arrDatos["numeros"] as $k=>$v){
    echo "key: $k  \t/\t value: $v".PHP_EOL;
}
```

La salida sería:

```
key: 19     /    value: 1
key: 8      /    value: 1
key: 30     /    value: 1
key: 31     /    value: 1
key: 35     /    value: 1
key: 45     /    value: 1
```

Comment: No tiene sentido entonces lo siguiente: *y cuando muestro la variable resultado me arroja lo de abajo: `{"numeros":{"19":1,"8":1,"30":1,"31":1,"35":1,"45":1}}`*. Si `$_POST["datos"]` es un array entonces `$resultado` no podría contener ese valor. También es cierto que debería respondernos a tu `print_r` o mi `var_dump` para que nos muestre lo que contiene realmente y también estaría bien saber cómo genera esos datos que envía desde javascript. PD: Yo no soy el que te acaba de poner un -1 (lo he visto en directo).

Comment: @OscarGarcia conozco tu altura como usuario de este sitio, los votos negativos silenciosos provienen sin duda de otro usuario. Lo cierto es que si `$_POST` es un array, no le veo ningún sentido a reconverir de nuevo a array un elemento que haya dentro de ese array... a no ser que ese elemento sea un JSON, lo cual sería extraño y entonces como dices, habrá que verificar cómo se están originando los elementos que hay dentro de `$_POST`.