# ¿Alguien me puede decir como puedo recorrer un array json?

Tags: php, json, curl

**Tengo este codigo pero me sale el siguiente error a la hora de mostrar un campo determinado que hay dentro de un arreglo.**

Errores:

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\JIRA\index.php on line 29
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\JIRA\index.php on line 31

Codigo:

```
<?php

function getSslPage($url){
//Este user y password los saco de Jira para hacer consultas de allí
$username = 'xxx';
$password = 'xxx';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $result;

}

function mostrarDatos(){

  //Acá ponga la consulta que deseo hacer

  $url = "xxx";

  $datos = getSslPage($url);
  
  $datos = json_decode($datos);

  $rs = $datos->results;

  foreach($rs as $name){
    var_dump($name);
    exit();
  }

}



 ?>

 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>Document</title>
 </head>
 <body>

 <?php mostrarDatos();?>
   
 </body>
 </html>
```

**Acá está el array json inicial al cual deseo recorrer para ir mostrando cada uno de sus campos, lo he intentado de muchas maneras y no encuentro solución alguna, trato de recorrerlo de distintas maneras con foreach pero siempre me sale error, en conclusión deseo poder recorrer todo el array json para listar cada uno de sus campos**

```
[
{
"expand": "description,lead,issueTypes,url,projectKeys,permissions,insight",
"self": "https://tigoco.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/project/10048",
"id": "10048",
"key": "SS",
"name": "EL KUKU",
"avatarUrls": {
"48x48": "https://tigoco.atlassian.net/secure/projectavatar?pid=10048&avatarId=10558",
"24x24": "https://tigoco.atlassian.net/secure/projectavatar?size=small&s=small&pid=10048&avatarId=10558",
"16x16": "https://tigoco.atlassian.net/secure/projectavatar?size=xsmall&s=xsmall&pid=10048&avatarId=10558",
"32x32": "https://tigoco.atlassian.net/secure/projectavatar?size=medium&s=medium&pid=10048&avatarId=10558"
},
"projectCategory": {
"self": "https://tigoco.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/projectCategory/10000",
"id": "10000",
"name": "Fijo",
"description": "Proyectos de desarrollo para sistemas del negocio fijo"
},
"projectTypeKey": "software",
"simplified": false,
"style": "classic",
"isPrivate": false,
"properties": {}
},
{}
]
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Recorrer JSON en PHP](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/177744/recorrer-json-en-php)

Answer (score 0):

Si el objeto que estás mostrando se devuelve tal cual lo muestras, no veo el objeto "result" que intentas asignar en $rs. Puedes iterar directamente $datos.

```
    function mostrarDatos(){

  $datos = '[
  {
    "expand": "description,lead,issueTypes,url,projectKeys,permissions,insight",
    "self": "https://tigoco.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/project/10048",
    "id": "10048",
    "key": "SS",
    "name": "EL KUKU",
    "avatarUrls": {
      "48x48": "https://tigoco.atlassian.net/secure/projectavatar?pid=10048&avatarId=10558",
      "24x24": "https://tigoco.atlassian.net/secure/projectavatar?size=small&s=small&pid=10048&avatarId=10558",
      "16x16": "https://tigoco.atlassian.net/secure/projectavatar?size=xsmall&s=xsmall&pid=10048&avatarId=10558",
      "32x32": "https://tigoco.atlassian.net/secure/projectavatar?size=medium&s=medium&pid=10048&avatarId=10558"
    },
    "projectCategory":
      {
        "self": "https://tigoco.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/projectCategory/10000",
        "id": "10000",
        "name": "Fijo",
        "description": "Proyectos de desarrollo para sistemas del negocio fijo"
      },
    "projectTypeKey": "software",
    "simplified": false,
    "style": "classic",
    "isPrivate": false,
    "properties": {}
  }
]';
  
  $datos = json_decode($datos);

  foreach($datos as $name){
    var_dump($name);
    exit();
  }

}
```